# Force Test Methods Implementation for all methods defined in an Database Interface

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, design-patterns, visual-studio-2012

I am designing a solutions that is capable of changing DataSource from SQL to Oracle and SQLite.

For this I am using Unity Framework to implement Lazy Binding.

I have created an Interface and wrote all the database methods signature into it.

Now I am writing seperate classes(projects) for each data source and implementing this Interface.

What I want now is to create a Test Project that should ensure that all the methods defined in Interface must be taken in Test Project, this Test Project has separate Test Database

Is there any framework/pattern available to automatically force creating Test Methods.

If someone provide writing [TestMethod] attribute over method (when implement interface) and change the return type to Void , I think that will be enough.

What I actually want is to implement a test project which should enforce to create Test Methods for all the signature defined in Database Layer Interface.

I am using VS 2012 as a development environment.

If I don't get any ready made solutions, How can I use Reflection to Implement methods to Test Project and change its signature at design time.( Is this weird requirement?)

Let me know if require more details.

Suggestions are Welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about any specific pattern here, but what I do for this scenario is this:

1. Reference the project where the interface is to the test project
2. Implement the interface in CRUDProviderMock.cs or something similar
3. Use the mock class for tests

I do believe I'm not the only one doing this as I've seen many companies applying this practise.

A sample project is here:
https://databaselayertesting.codeplex.com/

Sample project uses [Repository Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx) and [NUnit framework](http://www.nunit.org/) for testing,
where:

1. IRepository is CRUD interface for database
2. EntityOne is sample database entity
3. EntityOneRepositoryMock is mock IRepository implementation which uses lists

You can use sample database instead of lists to simulate real database behaviour.

Comment: can you provide more details on this practise?

Comment: Aaah... Describe what kind of details you want :) Sample or something else?

Comment: I will create sample VS 2012 solution :)

Answer (score 0):

I do realize that this issue is old and my solution does not target VS2012 nor the limitations of earlier versions of NUnit. However, I find your problem otherwise exactly the same as in modern environment. I also stumbled on this and found a suitable solution I think might fit others, or my future self, answering your requirements:

> What I want now is to create a Test Project that should ensure that
>   all the methods defined in Interface must be taken...
>
> Is there any framework/pattern available to automatically force
>   creating Test Methods.

By use of `TestCaseSource` in combination with the adaptor pattern I was able to enforce that any subsequent change of the interface will make the programmer having to update the tests as well. The beauty against use of reflection is that this will give you early compile time errors and that test faults are easier to track down by running specific tests.

The code below is very schematic. My own use was to combine it with mock of specific data to the `testObject` and verify that some specific exception was always thrown. A limitation is that the setup of the `testObject` is shared and therefore most suitable for simplier scenarios.

Testing code:

```
[TestFixture()]
public class SpecificDatabaseTest : IDatabase
{
    private SpecificDatabase testObject = new SpecificDatabase();
    private object TestObject = new object();
    private SomeObject TestSomeObject1 = new SomeObject();
    private SomeObject TestSomeObject2 = new SomeObject();

    public IEnumerable<TestCaseData> SomeMethodData
    {
        get
        {
            yield return new TestCaseData(TestObject).Returns(TestObject);    
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<TestCaseData> SomeOtherMethodData
    {
        get
        {
            yield return new TestCaseData(TestSomeObject1, TestSomeObject2).Returns(TestSomeObject2);
            yield return new TestCaseData(TestSomeObject2, TestSomeObject1).Returns(TestSomeObject1);
        }
    }

    [Test, TestCaseSource(nameof(SomeMethodData))]
    public object SomeMethod(object data)
    {
        return testObject.SomeMethod(data);
    }

    [Test, TestCaseSource(nameof(SomeOtherMethodData))]
    public SomeObject SomeOtherMethod(SomeObject data1, SomeObject data2)
    {
        return testObject.SomeOtherMethod(data1, data2);
    }
}
```

Other code:

```
public interface IDatabase
{
    object SomeMethod(object data);

    SomeObject SomeOtherMethod(SomeObject data1, SomeObject data2);
}

public class SpecificDatabase : IDatabase
{
    public object SomeMethod(object data)
    {
        return data;
    }

    public SomeObject SomeOtherMethod(SomeObject data1, SomeObject data2)
    {
        return data2;
    }
}

public class SomeObject { }
```